# Linq Query: Distinct Year + Dynamic Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to take a DateTime field and create a List of DateObject, where DateObject has 2 properties (**Year** and *Range*). I want to identify the year of the DateTime field then... If it's even, I want to retain that year for **Year**. If it's odd, I want to change it to year - 1 for **Year**.

Then, based off that, I want to identify a string for *Range* that will look like "[EvenYear] to [EvenYear + 1]".

My data looks like this:

TableData

- ID (i.e., 1)
- Date (i.e., 12/7/2017)

If the records look like:

- ID: 1, Date: 12/7/2017 (2017 should change to 2016)
- ID: 2, Date: 1/1/2016 (keeps 2016)
- ID: 3, Date: 1/2/2016 (keeps 2016)
- ID: 4, Date: 10/5/2015 (2015 would be 2014)

I want the output List of DateObjects to look like this (distinct based off the **Year**):

- **Year**: 2014, *Range*: 2014 to 2015
- **Year**: 2016, Range: 2016 to 2017

I am so frustrated with figuring this out. I've tried a lot of code.

This is the code I left off with that kept failing:

```
var sessionYears = db.tblDates.GroupBy(x => (x.Date.Year % 2 == 0 ? x.Date.Year : x.Date.Year - 1)).ToList();

return sessionYears.Select(x => new List<DateObject>                {
StartYear= x.Key,
Range = x.Select(y => y.Date.Year + " to " + (y.Date.Year + 1))
}
```

I've tried messing around with distinct and groupby, but I am clearly missing some steps, etc. I can't find anything online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using two selects after each other? Why not create a `DateRangeObject` in the first select?

Comment: @Jerodev I updated to what I changed it to last. I think I was just attempting multiple things, and was stacking them and commenting other things out, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the list of `DateRangeObject` first and after that get the distinct values. This will make your query much simpler.

```
return db.tblDates
    .Select(x => new DateRangeObject {
        StartYear = x.Date.Year % 2 == 0 ? x.Date.Year : x.Date.Year - 1,
        EndYear = (x.Date.Year % 2 == 0 ? x.Date.Year : x.Date.Year - 1) + " - " + ((x.Date.Year % 2 == 0 ? x.Date.Year : x.Date.Year - 1) + 1);
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.StartYear)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry if it was unclear, but the EndYear should be a string that says basically "Year1 to Year2". I'll try your method, though. :)

Comment: It's not that much of a change to make `EndYear` a string, I updated my answer. :)

Comment: dbContext.tblDates is IQueryable, not IEnumerable. I would have expected that IQueryable does not know how to create EndYear.

Comment: Hmm, okay, so I got to the EndYear = $"{..." piece, but that just failed. I've never seen that kind of code in linq before. Is that a typo? I changed it to... EndYear = startYear + " - " + (startYear + 1)... but now I get an error: at the x => (after the first Select). It states: a lambda with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: I have updated my answer to not use a statement body

Comment: `$""` is actually a shorthand for `string.format("")` since C#6. But it seems EF can't handle that.

Comment: @Jerodev Ohh, thanks for the note about $"". :) Everything looks good now up til the .ToList(). It states: Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<IGrouping<int,DateRangeObject>> to List<DateRangeObject>. Apologies for all the Qs - thank you for all the help. :)

Comment: Did you add the last `Select` from my example? I think you forgot the one under the `GroupBy`.

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out. :) I had to change the last .Select to .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()) --- instead of just First().  Thank you much!! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. There is no need to update your question with the answer. Otherwise, people with the same problem wouldn't be able to find this question. Also, if this worked, consider marking my solution as the answer. :)

Comment: @Jerodev I think I accepted it as the answer with the green checkmark. :) New to posting. I have another Q posted, if you have time to take a look. :) :) Otherwise, no worries! I'll figure it out eventually. Thank you again!!